# How should I connect multiple BLE peripherals to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Currently my team is calling

```
[myCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
```

and then starting an `NSTimer` that fires in two seconds. During these two seconds, the Central Manager delegate method

`centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:`

is used to create an array of `CBPeripherals` that we are interested in.

When the timer fires, we call `connectPeripheral` on every item in the array within a for loop.

I am worried that this is not the best way to connect to several devices at once. Should we wait for one device's connection process to complete before calling `connectPeripheral` on another device?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: As an aside, you can limit the peripherals you hear about to only the ones you're interested in if you pass an array of service UUIDs into `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`.

Comment: That's a good point. We have created our own peripherals and are only accepting services that our peripherals offer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you experienced issues? If not, then do it the way you do.

Some additional thoughts:

- Generally, it is advised to stop scanning before starting a connection request. The connection will be established significantly faster this way.
- Starting multiple connections at once has no implications from the API side, however, it's possibly safer (from a robustness point of view) to do it sequentially. This way you can prevent overloading the Core Bluetooth stack.
- Instead of an NSTimer, I'd rather use the GCD [dispatch_after](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after) function but this is my personal preference. (Using ReactiveCocoa would be even better.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips. The main concern is robustness which I failed to mention. I tried a sequential approach today and found that it worked to my likings. I went ahead and marked this as the correct answer.

If you have a moment, would you have any clues as to why I am constantly receiving a timeout message after calling DiscoverServices on a peripheral within the connectPeripheral method?

Comment: You can discover only after the didConnect callback happened. Do you consider this in your code?

Comment: Yes, a lot of our code is based on the Apple core-bluetooth documentation. We are able to create many successful connections, and then suddenly the connection attempts stop when we try discoverServices. I had an idea today that may be helpful. After the successful connection is made to a peripheral, we can store its services and characteristics. I am going to try subscribing to a known peripheral's characteristics, and forego the discoverServices routine of a peripheral we are already familiar with.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Services are cached by the framework as much as possible. You should not try to be smarter than that as it will just result in failed attempts. Services, characteristics, peripherals, nothing can be stored. You should rather try to avoid overlapping operation between peripherals. Unfortunately, the stack seems still not to be very stable with several connected devices and frequent connect/disconnect events. Alternatively, you may give a try to the Multipeer Connectivity framework if you connect multiple iOS devices.